# What are steps involved in buidling and CodeIgniter application?

Tags: codeigniter

sorry for asking an weird question

My question is about steps before coding. I mean if we want to build an CI app, normally how should we start (knowing our requirements)? How do we brainstorm? After brainstormed, where should we start coding at, i.e. View, or Controller? etc.

Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should design the database and program model, after that start controller, because you will need model in controller.

I usually start view after them, but some one prefer to design the views first. It depends on yourself.